# How do I use my house storage for crafting?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

I like to use my house storage to contain all of the materials and stuff I inevitably hoard. Is there a way to use this storage when crafting instead of my pockets? I have a DIY workbench in the house but it doesn't seem to let me switch storage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My technique is to have the crafting bench in your house. So you can always just exit out of the bench and access the storage anytime, instead of having to go back to your house.

Thats the closest I could do to craft from storage.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, and less than ideal but if easier, you can pile materials on the floor for easiest retrieval.